# How can I use the type guard of the parent interface in the type guard of the child interface?

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces, a parent interface and an interface that extends it:

```js
interface Base {
  foo: boolean;
}

interface ExtendsBase extends Base {
  bar: boolean;
}
```

And I have a user-defined type guard for the base class:

```js
function isBase(value: any): value is Base {
  return value && 'foo' in value && typeof value.foo === 'boolean';
}
```

I'd like to make use of that type guard when writing the type guard of the `ExtendsBase` interface:

```js
function isExtendsBase(value: any): value is ExtendsBase {
  return isBase(value) && 'bar' in value && typeof value.bar === 'boolean';
}                                                        ~~~
```

The first part of the expression, `isFoo(value)`, evaluates to `value: Base`. With the second part of the expression, `isFoo(value) && 'bar' in value` evaluates to `value: never`. And in the full expression, I get the following error:

> Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'never'.

The goal, here, is to be able to use the code from `isBase` in `isExtendsBase` to follow the DRY principle, and in examples potentially much more complex than this one. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution : Just swap it around:

```
function isExtendsBase(value: any): value is ExtendsBase {
  return  'bar' in value && typeof value.bar === 'boolean' && isBase(value);
}
```

If you really want the bar checks to happen first, recast to any.

```
function isExtendsBase(value: any): value is ExtendsBase {
  return isBase(value) as any && 'bar' in value && typeof value.bar === 'boolean'  ;
}
```

Comment: This would still require some repetition from `isBase`, however, as I'd want to first check that `value` is truthy. Also, if the example were more complex, there'd potentially be even more repetition.

Comment: I had no idea you could type cast the type guard, itself! +1